# Did Firefox 6 change its rendering engine?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook, firefox

Did Firefox's rendering engine change between versions 4/5 and version 6?

When I go to a highly graphical site like http://valentino.com/ with Firefox 6, it seems that the initial access takes a lot longer than it used to, and then the whole site is all on screen at once. The same site in Chrome 13 loads like I am used to: fast initial access, with the elements appearing as they are loaded.

Basically, I'm wondering why the Internet seems slower than it did a few days ago.

I'm using Firefox 6.0.1 on a white Macbook that runs OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they changed it. I think they have upgraded it. Firefox 6 is using Gecko 6.0.

Refer the following links for all the changes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_6_for_developers

http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/6.0/releasenotes/

Comment: Thanks for the links. Looking through them, I do not recognise anything specifically related to my question, but since your's is the only answer, and the links should be relevant, I accept it.